# Which Selector Matched in a Stylus Rule Set?

Tags: selector, rules, stylus

Is there anyway to grab the name of the class that matched in a stylus rule set?

What I'm trying to do is dry up this rule (and many like it):

```
.button
  &:hover
    button-hover-color-scheme(teal)
    &.adwords
      button-hover-color-scheme(adwords)
    &.bingads
      button-hover-color-scheme(bingads)
    &.facebook
      button-hover-color-scheme(facebook)
    &.linkedin
      button-hover-color-scheme(linkedin)
    &.twitter
      button-hover-color-scheme(twitter)
```

I'd like to make it look something like this:

```
.button
  &:hover
    button-hover-color-scheme(teal)
    &.adwords
    &.bingads
    &.facebook
    &.linkedin
    &.twitter
      button-hover-color-scheme(matched-selector)
```

where `matched-selector` would be whichever one of `adwords, bingads, facebook, linkedin, or twitter` actually matched the rule.

Thanks!

Edit:

There is the [selector()](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/selectors.html#selector-bif) function but it's giving me the entire selector not just the last piece to match. It's almost what I need but I feel like there must be a simpler way to refer to matched selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Panya's answer I started trying to use interpolation to solve this and came up with:

```
.button
  &:hover
    for network in 'google' 'bing' 'facebook' 'linkedin' 'twitter'
      &.{network}
        button-hover-color-scheme(lookup(network))
```

The trick was to loop over a list of strings, use brackets for the selector and lookup to convert the string back into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the matched selector, because this selector will be defined only in the browser runtime. At that moment there won't be any Stylus code, because browser will use CSS that was compiled by Stylus.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense and helps me think about this in the right way. Maybe I can try [interpolation](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/interpolation.html#selector-interpolation) to get what I want.

Comment: Yep, the only way to avoid this duplication is interpolation + loops.